# Display:none css issue

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am having an issue. I have css like this one below

```
select {
width:100%;
}
```

this is for my select option. The issue is that on the web browser i have (that is how it is on notepad++) but in Inspect element I am getting `<select id="custom" style="display: none;">`

you will notice `style="display: none;` i didn't know write this, the browser just added it.

How can I stop this?

I have clear everything in my browser both the firefox and chrome and still no changes

Comment: Do you have any javascript which might add the display none?

Comment: @Xeano i deleted all my javascript file to make sure and it not it. I deleted my ajax too and its not them.

Comment: Just to make sure, have you tried to disable javascript in your browser and then go to the site?

Comment: @Xeano i disable javascript and it works. I deleted all my javascript and ajax and I mean all of them but it doesnt work this work. Anyways On the inspect element i am getting error with this chrome script. which I am not using. chrome-[Apply UsePageDelay: true UsePageEvent false](chrome-extension://jgceplfonlgodadnpognljgdjlcnpjnh/content_script.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are very few options here if it's not in your html, and you are not browsing something cached. Then it must come from javascript. Try search for "display" within your project/files - and check your javascript references.

You can ***try and disable javascript***, just to be 100% sure that's the cause. From there you can figure out which script does it.

Comment: I found the issue. it was the ` * jQuery JavaScript Library v1.9.1
 * http://jquery.com/` that I am using but i dont understand why it is display:none for this partially select option.

Comment: No that makes no sense, unless there has been some edits to the script. Sorry for the late response, but I couldn't help you find which script does it, as I cannot see your project/files. Glad you figured it out!

Comment: thanks for your help and your patience in this question. I fixed the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Double check any Javascript you have that references your `select`/`#custom` element. I know when using jQuery, certain functions (like `slideToggle()`) will add style attributes directly to the HTML element. If that *is* the case, you can counter it using jQuery's `css()`